# Domino 8.5.3 forward room reservation request to external email

Tags: calendar, ibm-domino, email

I have created a room reservation database on my notes server. Now my problem is that we have 2 company that will use this room and I would like to forward the meeting request sent to this room to external email address so that the other company email server receive the reservation request and update the calendar on their side to see the accurate availability of the room. How can I achive this.

Thanks !

Comment: Just a few questions: 1) Does the external company use Lotus Notes?
2) What version of Lotus Domino server are you running? 3) Can your Lotus Domino server be seen externally?

Comment: 1- yes they also use domino 2- 8.5.3 is the version 3-if it can be seen is a tough question as it depend on what you mean exactly, it receive and forward mail and my user can connect from outside to it so I would say that yes it can be visible from outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both companies use Lotus Domino you could cross certify them, and then replicate your rooms and reservation over to the other one.

Comment: That's what we ended up doing.